# How do I add a button to an Android Frame Layout, in the same position as my picture (centered in the bottom 4th of the screen)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-framelayout

This is an Android question.

**How do I add a button to a frame layout, in the same location as my picture?**

I am trying to add a button on top of a frame layout (which has a background image and no title bar) like so:

[image]

This is the entire code of my layout so far. What code do I add to put a button like in the picture?

**activity_home_page.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/my_background_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>



</FrameLayout>
```

**How do I add a button to a frame layout, in the same location as my picture?**

Comment: what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: How do I add a button to a Frame layout in the same position as in the picture?

Comment: which control are you used in background??

Comment: @Rv Panchal I'm sorry, but I can't understand your English. The background image is an ImageView.

Comment: @RockLee I have come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried & come up with a solution.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mod_minecraft"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! It tried it and it works perfectly and does exactly what I wanted it to do.